# best combination for creating a mobile application in MVC3 framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

what would be the best combination for creating a mobile application using MVC3 framework, MVC framework with jquery mobile or any any other?? I'm, completely new to jquery mobile and mobile apps development, any suggestions regarding how to get started with jquery mobile in MVC3?I want to develop some sample mobile app for understanding purpose..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Sencha UI](http://www.sencha.com/)

   One year ago it was the best solution, much better then jQuery Mobile and Kendo UI. If you don't mind its UI it still has a much better support for MVC style application design.
2. [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/)

   Currently jQuery Mobile is probably most commonly used js mobile application framework. You will find a huge number of available tutorials, and (unlike JSP and PHP) MVC3 is safe bet here.
3. [Kendo UI](http://www.kendoui.com/)

   Less good tutorials and support but it has a much better support for MVC style application design then jQuery Mobile and a much faster learning curve then Sencha UI.
4. jqTouch

   It can be used with MVC3 but available support is slim to none.
5. [jQMobi](http://app-framework-software.intel.com/) (now also known as Intel app framework)

   It can be used with MVC3 but available support is slim to none.

**Final thoughts:**

Stick with Kendo UI if you are using a full potential of MVC3 or doing a professional and complex web app. Stick with jQM in any other case, mostly if you don't want to go beyond jquery syntax. Skip Sencha UI, you will spend too much time learning it.

Comment: how about html5 + mvc3??....can i get a sample app with mvc3+ jquery mobile, actually i want to develop video capturing mobile app

Comment: you can use html5+mvc3+phonegap to create a video capturing mobile app but I would advise using a mobile framework because it is relatively hard to create a responsive HTML from scratch.

Comment: so accrding to you,with mvc3+jquery mobile+html5 can we capture images and videos?

Comment: You also need a Phonegap mobile app wrapper, only it can give you an ability to record video and pictures. http://phonegap.com/

Comment: so, all the 4 including phonegap are must for creating a mobile app for capturing images and videos,can u guide how to start forst, likeintegrating jqery mobile etcc, tried but not able to find a sample app whcih uses jquery mobile and mvc3?

Comment: Google it, there are a lot of them. For example : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852592.aspx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22879/discussion-between-colors-bright-and-gajotres)

Comment: @Gajotres - why do you say jqMobi support is slim to none?  Questions are answered all the time on here, official forums and twitter (I think you are confusing corporate source vs open source)

Comment: I can confirm that - i opened a bug ticket a few weeks ago (on the weekend). On Monday i received an email that they (well i guess that's Ian most of the time ;) ) had immediately fixed the bug, patched code was already in the github repository. That's real value for money... errr wait - what money? Luv those guys the longer i work with their (well, now intels) product.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [jquery](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/) mobile or [kendo ui](http://www.kendoui.com/) or [sencha](http://www.sencha.com/)

Comment: kendo ui is 3rd part right? aslo is kendo provinding support for mobile apps , as i know only about kendo grids..

Comment: kendo ui has document for developing you can use.

Comment: you can use kendo ui with jsonresult in mvc.net is the best ui for web application.

Comment: no but i think its 3rd party paid control?

Comment: you can use free licence http://www.kendoui.com/download.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Having evaluated a couple of options over the last year, including building whole apps with JQMobi as well as JQuery Mobile, i'd say the decision is merely a marketing / usability concern rather than a coding style / framework decision.

Currently still [~50% of Android phones are running version 2.x](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) - i own one of those buggers and the performance is really challenging (at best). If you want to provide a nice user experience on those phones you will really want to try [jQMobi](http://app-framework-software.intel.com/api/), as performance-wise it's the [hands-down winner](http://www.codefessions.com/2012/08/performance-of-jquery-compatible-mobile.html). If you're OK with buggy or slow transitions and poor usability on those phones, take any other framework. Just my two cents from experience so far.

Cannot advise on MVC3 integration, that will be possible to work along any ajax application i guess. As a beginner, i strongly advice you to take at testdrive at [AppMobi's free XDK](http://www.html5m.com/) that Intel just took over last week (together with jqMobi and the whole staff, so there's a lot of momentum in this project). It has everything you need to built a full app (with one of the best performing solutions to tackle HTML5 audio and video, from what i've read), w/o the need to install any the additional XDK, set up a phonegap project, and so on...